# Why isn't CADisplayLink working in this case?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cadisplaylink

I want to use CADisplayLink instead of NSTimer for an animation of a ball which is just moving, but with CADisplayLink it doesn't work.  What could be the problem in the following code?

```
#import "UntitledViewController.h"


@implementation UntitledViewController
@synthesize maBalle;


-(void) update:(CADisplayLink*)displayLink {
}

-(void)topHorloge {
    maBalle.center =CGPointMake(maBalle.center.x+coordonnees.x,maBalle.center.y+coordonnees.y);
    if((maBalle.center.x)-20 <0 || (maBalle.center.x)+20 >320)
        coordonnees.x=-coordonnees.x;
    if((maBalle.center.y)-20 <0 || (maBalle.center.y)+20 >460)
        coordonnees.y=-coordonnees.y;
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(renderAndUpdate)];
    [displayLink setFrameInterval:2];
    [displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];


}
```

Comment: You need to format all of the code or you may not get an answer anytime soon **{}**

Comment: As hotpaw2 indicates, you're missing chunks of code in your sample here.  Where is your `-renderAndUpdate` method that handles the CADisplayLink callback?

Answer (score 1):

Where is your  renderAndUpdate  handler?  (which you specified as your displaylink callback)

Comment: no renderAnUpdate is topHorloge. But now it work. but another problem is that when I use CADisplayLink first  it's 60fps but after 2 second it's 40fps. What can I do to solve this problem ?